# How do I centre a block of text but keep the alignment to the left HTML?

Tags: html

I want to centralise the below text but keep the text alignment to the left. i.e. I want to keep the left margin the same size for each line of text:

```
<li>Stainless steel capacity: 0.5mm<br />
<li>Aluminum, copper, zinc, steel capacity: 0.8mm<br />
<li>Steel, Plastisol capacity: 0.8mm<br />
<li>Length: 310mm<br />
<li>Width: 320 - 610mm<br />
<li>Closing length: 210mm<br />
<li>Weight: 3.3kg<br /></li>
```

Comment: Seems like CSS would work just fine here. What have you tried?

Comment: Wrap your list in an inline-block container, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The `margin:auto` property centres items, providing you have a width.

```css
ul{
  max-width:700px;
  margin:auto;
  list-style: inside;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place it in a `<div>` container which is centered using `margin:0;` and its parent set to `display:flex;`

Your list items `<li>` needed to have their own closing tags each `</li>` even these little errors can cause an entire web page to not work also it's just `<br>`

Code 
`<div class="list-container"> <ul> <li>Stainless steel capacity: 0.5mm</li><br> <li>Aluminum, copper, zinc, steel capacity: 0.8mm</li><br> <li>Steel, Plastisol capacity: 0.8mm</li><br> <li>Length: 310mm</li><br> <li>Width: 320 - 610mm</li><br> <li>Closing length: 210mm</li><br> <li>Weight: 3.3kg</li><br> </ul> </div>`

 then in your head you will need to add this style...

```
<style>
        .list-container {
            display: flex;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .list-container ul {
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm completely new to coding. Please could you explain how I would do this with the below code?
<li>Stainless steel capacity: 0.5mm<br />
<li>Aluminum, copper, zinc, steel capacity: 0.8mm<br />
<li>Steel, Plastisol capacity: 0.8mm<br />
<li>Length: 310mm<br />
<li>Width: 320 - 610mm<br />
<li>Closing length: 210mm<br />
<li>Weight: 3.3kg<br /></li>

Comment: `<div class="list-container">
        <ul>
            <li>Stainless steel capacity: 0.5mm</li><br>
            <li>Aluminum, copper, zinc, steel capacity: 0.8mm</li><br>
            <li>Steel, Plastisol capacity: 0.8mm</li><br>
            <li>Length: 310mm</li><br>
            <li>Width: 320 - 610mm</li><br>
            <li>Closing length: 210mm</li><br>
            <li>Weight: 3.3kg</li><br>
        </ul>
    </div>`